# Cannot install PEAR mail package XAMPP on Windows

Tags: windows, email, installation, xampp, package

From the cmd line:

```
C:\Users\Lemur>pear install --onlyreqdeps Mail

Did not download optional dependencies: pear/Net_SMTP, use --alldeps to download automatically
pear/Mail can optionally use package "pear/Net_SMTP" (version >= 1.4.1)
downloading Mail-1.3.0.tgz ...
Starting to download Mail-1.3.0.tgz (23,110 bytes)
........done: 23,110 bytes
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\tests\Mail\tests
```

I see a newly created Mail folder in xampp\php\pear\Mail, which is correct, but the folder has no contents.

Also, the Error shows that install is attempting to put something at C:\php\pear\tests\Mail\tests.  There is no such directory C:\php\pear...

What is wrong?  Include_path in php.ini is correct (C:\xampp\php\pear).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using a different method, I tried: php pyrus.phar install Mail-1.3.0 only to have the system come back with
Pyrus\XMLParser\Exception: Invalid XML document
 Pyrus\XMLParser\Exception: Line 2: Element '{http://pear2.php.net/dtd/customcommand-2.0}commands', attribute 'version': The value '(null)' does not match the fixed value constraint '2.0'.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: http://davehiren.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-or-uninstall-pear.html.  I'm using XAMPP and didn't realize all the path variables that needed to be changed.  Once I altered all the path variables, the Mail package installed just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For working with PEAR using XAMPP in Windows, it's important to avoid the command line in Windows and instead use the **XAMPP Shell**. Simply open the XAMPP Control Panel and click on XAMPP Shell on the right:

[image: Location of the Shell button in the XAMPP Control Panel]

In the XAMPP Shell, you can enter your PEAR package installation command as you normally would and the packages will get installed in their proper place within XAMPP's PHP directory:

`pear install --onlyreqdeps Mail`

Comment: getting this error in this process, Please help.
"PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use result of built-in function in write context in F:\xampp\php\pear\Archive\Tar.php on line 639

Fatal error: Cannot use result of built-in function in write context in F:\xampp\php\pear\Archive\Tar.php on line 639"

Comment: @HarishKumar I ran into that issue as well and used the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50347729/xampp-how-to-upgrade-pear).