# XAMPP: How to upgrade PEAR

Tags: php, xampp

When trying to upgrade XAMPP pear the following error is raised:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use result of built-in function in write context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Archive\Tar.php on line 639
```

Some suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: // ----- Get the arguments
        $v_att_list = & func_get_args(); when i remove & symbol another error apear. That is      ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\Archive_Tar\docs

Comment: the below lines $v_att_list = & func_get_args();

Comment: I remove the & but another error occured.

Comment: i would ditch xampp and use a real dev server on a vm. try docker. i can give you a config if you like, you'll have a full server up in 15 mins

Comment: @delboy1978uk I would be glad to get the config.

Comment: Here you go, just download it, `docker-machine start`, then `eval $(docker-machine env)`, then cd into the folder and finally `docker-compose up`. That's it! Edit your `/etc/hosts` or `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, and add `192.168.99.100 awesome.scot` to it. Now you can browse to your test server on http(s)://awesome.scot and start developing https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp/blob/master/build/httpd/Dockerfile

Comment: to get a command line in the docker machine, type `docker exec -it lamp_php1 /bin/bash`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just change in Tar.php

```
$v_att_list = & func_get_args();
```

to

```
$v_att_list = func_get_args();
```

PD:Tested over PHP 7.2 in Xammp

Comment: This still works. There was an error in C:\xampp\php\pear\Archive\Tar.php

Comment: There is a typo in your answer. You meant `=`. `&=` makes no sense here, it's the bitwise and + assign operator. I couldn't fix your answer because the robot says the edit must weigh at least 6 characters and I was just trying to delete one character.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means you have a function inside a fuction, and sometimes it doesn't like that.

As an example, if this caused the error:

```
if(!isset(Session::get($something))){
```

Then you could change it to this to fix the problem:

```
$value = Session::get($something);
if(!isset($value)){
```